# How to properly implement RESTful API PATCH method to update multiple entities with OneToMany relation based on Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to find a way to appropriately implement a mechanism for updating one or more child entities. Parent entity has OneToMany relation to none, one or more child entities and I need a way to update only the ones which are provided by the PATCH request.

So far I didn't find any enough specific example which would point me in the right direction.

The problem is, that with the current code it works like so:

1. If I use endpoints to add or update a single child item everything works fine.
2. If I provide all existing items in the PATCH request by the exactly aligned order (e.g. order of child items retrieved by the GET request) everything works fine.
3. If I provide mixed order of items it attempts to update items according to the original order (e.g. order of child items retrieved by the GET request) by the data provided in the PATCH request - that means I cannot patch e.g. 3rd item if I don't provide valid details for first two items in the exact order. If I provide IDs in the request it attempts to update those instead of using them to address particular item.

Here is a sample of a code:

Implementation of entities:

```php
class ParentEntity
{
    /** @var int */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|ChildEntity[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ChildEntity", mappedBy="parentEntity")
     */
    private $clindEntities;
}

class ChildEntity
{
    /** @var int */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ParentEntity
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ParentEntity", inversedBy="clindEntities")
     */
    private $parentEntity;

    /** @var string */
    private $someProperty;
}
```

Form types:

```php
class ParentEntityFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('clindEntities', Type\CollectionType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'entry_type' => ChildEntityFormType::class,
                'by_reference' => true,
                'allow_add' => false,
                'allow_delete' => false,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ParentEntity::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'allow_extra_fields' => false
        ]);
    }
}

class ChildEntityFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', Type\TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'trim' => true,
            ])
            ->add('someProperty', Type\TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'trim' => true,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ChildEntity::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'allow_extra_fields' => false
        ]);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```php
class EntityController extends ApiBaseController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/v1/parent-entity/{id}", methods={"PATCH"}, name="api.v1.parent_entity.update")
     */
    public function updateParentEntity(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em, string $id)
    {
        $parentEntityRepository = $em->getRepository(ParentEntity::class);
        $parentEntity = $parentEntityRepository->find($id);
        if (!$parentEntity) {
            $apiProblemInterface = new Ae\ApiProblemInterface(Ae\ApiProblemType::ENTITY_NOT_FOUND);
            throw new Ae\ApiProblemException($apiProblemInterface);
        }

        // Validate payload
        $form = $this->createForm(ParentEntityFormType::class, $parentEntity);
        $this->submitAndValidateForm($form, $request, false, false);

        // Save changes
        $em->flush();

        return $this->response($parentEntity, ['api_entity_metadata', 'api_parent_entity', 'api_clhild_entity'], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Original data structure and order (sample of ParentEntity):

```json
{
    "id": 22,
    "clindEntities": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "someProperty": "Some test string 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "someProperty": "Some test string 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "someProperty": "Some test string 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

So if I do the PATCH Request to `/api/v1/parent-entity/22`

```json
{
    "clindEntities": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "someProperty": "Updated test string 3"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "someProperty": "Updated test string 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

It would result in an attempt to change the data as follows (that, of course, fails due to the non-unique ID):

```json
{
    "id": 22,
    "clindEntities": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "someProperty": "Updated test string 3"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "someProperty": "Updated test string 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "someProperty": "Some test string 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

What approach should I use to achieve that only the child items with exact ID get updated no matter the order in which they are provided?

Is there any simplified way to iterate through the items provided by the request and put them through the Symfony form system separately?

PS: similarity this applies to the endpoint for adding child items using the POST method. Although there are not child IDs provided Symfony form system updates existing elements in the original order instead of adding new ones.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the iteration through child elements, submitting and validating them individually through the Symfony's form system:

```php
class EntityController extends ApiBaseController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/v1/parent-entity/{id}", methods={"PATCH"}, name="api.v1.parent_entity.update")
     */
    public function updateParentEntity(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em, string $id)
    {
        $parentEntityRepository = $em->getRepository(ParentEntity::class);
        $parentEntity = $parentEntityRepository->find($id);
        if (!$parentEntity) {
            $apiProblemInterface = new Ae\ApiProblemInterface(Ae\ApiProblemType::ENTITY_NOT_FOUND);
            throw new Ae\ApiProblemException($apiProblemInterface);
        }

        $childEntityRepository = $em->getRepository(ChildEntity::class);
        foreach ($data['childEntities'] as $childEntity) {
            if (!isset($childEntity['id'])) {
                $apiProblemInterface = new Ae\ApiProblemInterface(Ae\ApiProblemType::ENTITY_NOT_FOUND);
                throw new Ae\ApiProblemException($apiProblemInterface);
            }

            $childEntity = $childEntityRepository->find($childEntity['id']);
            if (!$childEntity) {
                $apiProblemInterface = new Ae\ApiProblemInterface(Ae\ApiProblemType::ENTITY_NOT_FOUND);
                throw new Ae\ApiProblemException($apiProblemInterface);
            }

            $form = $this->createForm(AccountCryptoType::class, $childEntity);
            $this->submitArrayAndValidateForm($form, $accountData, false, false);
        }

        // Validate payload
        $form = $this->createForm(ParentEntityFormType::class, $parentEntity);
        $this->submitAndValidateForm($form, $request, false, false);

        // Save changes
        $em->flush();

        return $this->response($parentEntity, ['api_entity_metadata', 'api_parent_entity', 'api_clhild_entity'], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    /**
     * Reusable helper method for form data submission and validation.
     */
    protected function submitArrayAndValidateForm(FormInterface $form, array $formData, bool $clearMissing = true)
    {
        $form->submit($formData, $clearMissing);

        // Validate
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            return;
        }
        $formErrors = $form->getErrors(true);

        // Object $formErrors can be string casted but we rather use custom stringification for more details
        if (count($formErrors)) {
            $errors = [];
            foreach ($formErrors as $formError) {
                $fieldName = $formError->getOrigin()->getName();
                $message = implode(', ', $formError->getMessageParameters());
                $message = str_replace('"', "*", $message);
                $messageTemplate = $formError->getMessageTemplate();
                $errors[] = sprintf('%s: %s %s', $fieldName, $messageTemplate, $message);
            }
        }

        $apiProblemInterface = new Ae\ApiProblemInterface(Ae\ApiProblemType::MISSING_OR_INVALID_PAYLOAD, join("; ", $errors));
        throw new Ae\ApiProblemException($apiProblemInterface);
    }
}
```

This works satisfactorily well. But yeah... if there is any better to achieve equivalent functionality, then please let me know and potentially help others who may have similar dificulties.

PS:

```php
$apiProblemInterface = new Ae\ApiProblemInterface(Ae\ApiProblemType::MISSING_OR_INVALID_PAYLOAD, "...");
throw new Ae\ApiProblemException($apiProblemInterface);
```

is just some custom way of implementation of \Throwable and exception handling mechanism. It can be understood as:

```php
throw new \Exception('Some message ...');
```

with the difference that it results in an API response with error HTTP code, content-type: application/problem+json and helper message within the payload (based on the defined type of the problem).